# Error relacionado con la red. Conexion local de SQL y C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando con visual studio en C# con una conexion local de SQL server manager 18.

El error dice " Error relacionado con la red o especifico de la instancia mientras se establecía conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o este no esta accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL este configurado para recibir conexiones remotas "

**Cadena de conexion**

```
static string CadenaConexion = Properties.Settings.Default.cn;
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(CadenaConexion);
```

**Linea en la que me da error**

```
ad.Fill(tabla);
```

Estoy probando esto en la computadora del cliente, porque aquí es donde tira el error, En la pc donde lo desarrolle funciona perfectamente.

Soy novato en esto, necesito ayuda.

Comment: El código que compartes no aporta nada. Lo que debes hacer es revisar como está configurado tu entorno de desarrollo y revisar si las condiciones son iguales en la pc del cliente. Si es conexión local, el cliente tiene instalado el SQL Server?

Comment: Si, instale la misma versión con el cual lo desarrolle

Comment: la cadena de conexión a donde apunta, es un servidor local, o es remoto

Comment: Es un servidor local, se ejecuta en la misma pc